# The text in the dxDatagrid should be automatically in selected mode on cell click

Tags: devexpress

I need the text that is available in the dxDataGrid should be in selected mode on clicking that cell in edit mode..??

I have even tried onCellClick event too..But no where I found the solution..

`onCellClick:function(e){
                e.cellElement.select();
            },`

Please help me out...

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this problem too, this did the trick for me.

```
onRowClick: function (e) {
     $("input.dx-texteditor-input[type=text]").select();
},
```

The problem I noticed, was the timing of the call.  The contents to be selected cell aren't ready when the onCellClick fires.  By using the OnRowClick(which fires right after the onCellClick), the select is called after the cell is done rendering.  Probably several ways to do the actual select, the timing is the real issue.